# Spring SimpleJDBCInsert : insert query getting blocked when the column value extends the column length

Tags: spring

When I try to insert a record in a table using SimpleJDBCInsert and make the value of a column greater than the column length, the query does not execute, without throwing any exception, and blocking further code-flow.
When I check the Mysql fullprocesslist, after the code reaches the insert statmemt, the database on which the query is to be fired, shows in SLEEP

I rectified the issue by truncating the column value to the schema's column length in the application.

Sample code example:

```
public class BlogDaoImpl implements BlogDao {  
    private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;  
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertBlog;  

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {  
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
        this.insertBlog =   
                new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)  
                 .withTableName("BLOG");  
                 .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");  
    }  

    public void create(String name, Integer age, Long salary) {  
        Map parameters = new HashMap();  
        parameters.put("city_id", "Vancouver");  
        parameters.put("blogger", "Bay Max");   
        Number id = insertEmp.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);  
    }  


}
```

In this case if the city_id length in Mysql database is VARCHAR(2), the code gets blocked at Number line id = insertEmp.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);

Would be interested to know, should Spring not throw a JDBC Exception of 
Data truncation: Data too long for column or any other exception.

Comment: It will only throw an exception if there is a SQL exception else there will be nothing to throw.

Comment: @M.Deinum, MysqlJDBC driver does throw the Data truncation error exception when the data length is  greater than the column length in other situtations. What is happening in this case? Why is the executeAndReturnKey statement getting blocked. When I put a logger after the executeAndReturn key query, it does not log anything. Meaning the statement goes into a blocked state.